How do the different property callbacks in Prepar3D run?
I am attempting to develop a plugin for the Prepar3D flight simulator, but I am encountering difficulties in fully comprehending the inner workings of the RegisterProperty interface family.
The interface family receives various callback functions, including PPropertyCallback and PEventCallback, among others. These callbacks appear to be triggered in specific circumstances. Could you please clarify the triggering conditions for these callbacks?
Additionally, I am confused about the first argument of these interfaces, which is guidCategory. What does this term 'Category' signify? Is it a ID for user-defined class type? Furthermore, the third parameter named PropertyBaseUnits is also puzzling me. Could you please explain what it represents?
Here is the online doc (https://www.prepar3d.com/SDKv3/LearningCenter/simobjects/simobject_api_references.html), although I cannot fully get the details which are not showed, and the thing I can only do is speculation.

I edited your question a bit to make it clear what this "prepar3d" thing is, but you should edit your question to make it self-contained, ie copy (relevant bits of) the definitions of the interface and functions you are asking about.

Did you see the Creating properties and events sample from the Prepar3D learning center?

@Botje Yes I do. But it is not quite clear. For example, if I register a key event, I do not need to pass what key I'm going to listen (only a EVENTTYPE_NORMAL tells that I'm going to listen key press down/relase up events).  About Registration of property callback (PPropertyCallback), It seems like a callback triggered somewhere to get the property value, and the question is where, when and who will trigger this callback to fetch the property value? The sample is really simple, so much is hidden (༎ຶ⌑༎ຶ)

... Why do you care who reads the property? All your callback should do is return the then-current value for the property.

@Botje Yes, you are right. I find that there is a ControlMap.xml required to map input to properties. I guess a key maps to which propertiy's event-callback will be triggered is defined here.
